# Analyzing a stack sort algorithm's time complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, stack, big-o

I've been working through problems in Cracking the Coding Interview to prepare for some interviews. I was able to solve the stack sort problem but I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to reason about the time complexity. My solution was very similar to the one supplied in the book and I have tested it quite a bit so I'm sure it is correct. Any insight into the thought process one would go through to analyze this algorithm would be very appreciated. The book says it's O(n^2). Here is the algorithm:

```
def sort_stack(stack):
    temp_stack = Stack()
    while not stack.is_empty():
        v = stack.pop()
        if temp_stack.is_empty() or temp_stack.peek() <= v:
            temp_stack.push(v)
        else:
            while not temp_stack.is_empty() and temp_stack.peek() > v:
                stack.push(temp_stack.pop())
            temp_stack.push(v)
    while not temp_stack.is_empty():
        stack.push(temp_stack.pop())
```

As a side note: I used this approach to sort the stack in order to be within the constraints of the problem. I am aware that faster solutions exist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Outer loop has at least n iterations, I know that. Inner loop could have between, 0 and temp_stack.size iterations depending on the values. In the worst case, original stack is already sorted, we would have 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... (n -1) iterations... but I think that summation ends up as, n(n + 1) / 2 when we ignore constants that's n^2 on it's own. I thought I was on to something, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: or would analysis of inner loop be: 1/n + 2/n + 3/n + 4/n + .... (n-1)/n which we would consider to just be n?? It's late I'm going to bed >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the worst case, in which sorting each and every item in the stack requires completely emptying the temp stack. (This happens when trying to sort a reverse-sorted stack.)

What is the cost of emptying/refilling the temp stack for each item?
How many items are there?

Combining these should give O(n^2).

Comment: item 1 would require 0 pops of temp stack, item 2 would require 1 pop, item 3 would require 2 pops... item n would require n-1 pops. So in total we have 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ..... + N iterations of inner loop. Which is, N(N+1)/2 or 1/2(N^2 + N) which is O(n). I think what I was doing was mistakingly multiplying that by the N again for outer loop when the outer loop was already taken into account during the summation. I kept getting O(N^3).

Comment: Yes, that summation already computes the total number of temp stack pops. Although it does not include pushing "seen" items back into the temp stack, doubling the work to include it does not change the overall complexity. Taking a step back from analyzing your code line by line, I thought about it like this: Each new item you see will need O(n) pops/pushes to insert it into the temp stack. Repeating this n times results in O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the pushes. At first I didn't think they would double the work but then I realized I had to push again for every pop! I understand your point though that in asymptotic analysis doubling the work doesn't affect our overall complexity. Thanks for the time :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be an over-simplified approach to algorithm analysis, but whenever I see a nested loop, I think n^2. Three loops nested -- n^3, etc. As a rule of thumb for simple programs, count the nested loops. This is a pretty helpful tutorial: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/alganalysis/

Comment: That does work in a lot of cases, but I agree that it is an oversimplified approach. And this book points out that remembering 'templates' as you have mentioned isn't a deep understanding. Thank you for the input!